# How to get the map function to not return something?

Tags: iteration, sml, smlnj, currying, higher-order-functions

In sml nj, if you use the map function, your basically saying for each element `x` in a list, apply the function `f` on it, and return the list of the new values, but lets say `f` returns a string, and in `f` a comparison is done, if the comparison is true, then it returns the string, but if it's false, then it doesn't return anything, and nothing gets put into that list that map is currently building.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: You can't have a function in SML that doesn't return _anything_ - but you might have one that returns (), or the empty list, or NONE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `map`, use one of the variants of `fold` (either `foldl` or `foldr`). Another option is, of course, to simply do a `filter` before you do the `map`.

As a simple example, imagine that you want to return a list of squared integers, but only if the original integers are even numbers. A filter-then-map approach might look like:

```
fun square_evens xs =
  (List.map (fn x => x * x)) (List.filter (fn x => x mod 2 = 0) xs)
```

Or, you could use a `foldr` approach.

```
fun square_evens xs =
  List.foldr (fn (x, xs') =>
    if x mod 2 = 0
    then (x * x) :: xs'
    else xs') [] xs
```

Slightly longer, but arguably clearer, and probably more efficient.

Comment: is this a curried function? (using the foldr)

Comment: @omega: Yes, it is. You can find its documentation [here](http://standardml.org/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.foldr:VAL).